# how to merge two order by statements in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following relational schema

```
create table employeeb37(
employee_id int primary key,
last_name varchar(255),
first_name varchar(255),
middle_name varchar(255),
job_id references jobb37(job_id),
manager_id varchar(255),
hiredate date,
salary int,
comm int,
department_id int
)
```

I want to query the database by employee details according to their job_id in ascending order and salaries in descending order

but i am not getting proper result for

```
select * from employeeb37 order by job_id asc and salary desc
```

I want to know if there is any other possible solution for my problem

Comment: what do you mean by "not getting proper result" ?

Comment: _and_ is a boolean operation that only cares if the operands are 0, null or <>0, probably not what you want to order by.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about :

```
select * from employeeb37 order by job_id asc, salary desc
```

Answer (score 5):

Use comma (`,`) instead of `AND` in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM employeeb37 
ORDER BY job_id ASC, salary DESC
```

Have a look at [`ORDER BY` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html)

Answer (score 2):

Separate your **`COLUMN NAME`** and **`ORDER TYPE`** (**`ASC`** or **`DESC`**) by using **`,`**

```
select * from emp order by job_id ASC ,salary DESC
```